# multiplying number from 1 to N while adding 2 every time

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I have to write a C program that multiplies numbers from 1 to N.
N is scanned. Before multiplication, I have to increase each number by 2.
For example: N = 3 =>  (1+2)*(2+2)*(3+2) = 60
I have to only use while loop and print and scan function.

Example program:

```
Enter the value of N: 4
The result of multiplication: 360
```

This is my code and I am not sure what is wrong with this. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>



    int N;
    int count=1, ii, result;
    printf("Enter the value of N:");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    while (count<=N)
    {
        count ii = count + 2;
        ii = ii * ii ;  //three
                count++;
        
    }
    result = ii;
    printf("The result of multiplication: %d", result);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `(N+2)! / 2`

Comment: Tip: `x *= x` is the short form of `x = x * x`.

Comment: `count ii = ...` doesn't make any sense as both `count` and `ii` are variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for that series as a sum:

```c
const int N = 3;
int c = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
  c *= (i + 2);
}
```

Or in a more C-esque form:

```c
const int N = 3;
int c = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  c *= (i + 1 + 2);
}
```

Comment: I have to use while loop, since we did not learn for loop yet

Comment: You can easily adapt this to use `while`. It takes literally ten minutes to learn the `for` loop. It's not that complicated, and it will serve you well for years to come.

Answer (score 0):

```
   int main()
   {
       int N;
       int count=1, ii = 1, result;
       printf("Enter the value of N:");
       scanf("%d", &N);
       while (count<=N)
       {
           ii = ii * ( count + 2 };
           count++;
       }
       result = ii;
      printf("The result of multiplication: %d", result);
      return 0;
  }
```